# Kostache CSS and JS on page

Tags: kohana

How do I go about loading css and javascript in my template? I am using kostache and the template loads fine. I am trying not to load template files directly onto the templates themselves but rather do it via the VIEW.

Is this feasible?
From [this link](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/5722/mustache-kohana-module-for-v3-logic-less-views/p3)

```
   <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
{{>css}}{{>js}}
<title>{{title}}</title>
</head>
```

Doesn't say much about those. Are they partial views? If so, does that mean that I create partial views with normal HTML tags linking to css files?

I have this within my view

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->set(array(
        'reset_css_link' => URL::site('assets/css/reset.css'),
        'style_css_link' => URL::site('assets/css/style.css'),
    ));
```

How do I pass that to the template.mustache file and loop through it and display what I need to display. That is the part I can't figure out.

[Sample that seems to work:](https://github.com/synapsestudios/kohana-projecttemplate/blob/dev/0.7.x/application/templates/layout/default.mustache)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used Kostache myself (yet!) but studied it briefly a few days ago. As far as I understand it, such things should probably go into your View_Layout class, have a look at how the default View_Layout class does things in Kostache and extend that class in your project.

https://github.com/zombor/KOstache/blob/master/classes/view/kohana/layout.php

This discussion is probably of good help as well:
http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/5722/mustache-kohana-module-for-v3-logic-less-views/p3

Comment: I have looked at both. None of them actually have anything that shows how to include js or css files.

Comment: All that should be needed is putting for instance all your js files in an array, and within the View, loop through that array and echo out the needed script tags. Just like one would've done with the "old" template system. I mean, including JS or CSS files is just markup, like any other markup :)

Comment: Afaik, if you add a function for returning for instance your CSS files you can then echo those within the template, look at http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/comment/46073#Comment_46073

Comment: And yes, the > stuff is using partials, look at the partials section of http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html

Comment: Finally taking shape. I just need to fix my array to render well.

Comment: @StefanHållén let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1498/discussion-between-kenyana-and-stefan-hallen)